# How to deploy log4j version2 in JavaFx project without using Maven

Tags: java, log4j2, documentum

I am doing a `JavaFx` project connected to Documentum data storage and I am trying to add the logging feature using `Log4jV2` I have already downloaded the file and added the following Jars  in to my libraries file . (`log4j-api-2.6.2.jar , log4j-core-2.6.2.jar`) and successfully imported the followings :

```
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
```

Then I created a file called config.xml with the following content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.apache.log4j.xml" level="info"/>
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
```

and placed it in my source file next to my other classes then started to configure it as beloew :

```
public class BGMController implements Initializable {
    static final org.apache.log4j.Logger logger =  LogManager.getLogger(BGMController.class.getName());

/////other content of my program /////////////////

public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
     DOMConfigurator.configure("config.xml");

    //  createCheckbox();
    //  createTable();

        logger.warn(" test Sample warn message");
        logger.error(" test Sample error message");
        logger.fatal(" test  Sample fatal message");
        logger.debug(" test Sample debug message");
        logger.info("  test Sample info message");



    }


}
```

As a result I get all these errors plus my Error , warn , fatal seems to be working fine and not the debug and info  :

Any idea how can I fix this . it has taken me quite a few days and I have no idea where am I doing my mistake :|

```
    0 [JavaFX Application Thread] ERROR com.documentum.fc.common.impl.logging.LoggingConfigurator  - Problem locating log4j configuration
    3 [JavaFX Application Thread] WARN com.documentum.fc.common.impl.logging.LoggingConfigurator  - Using default log4j configuration :
```

Answer (score 1):

Those messages are from Log4j1. You should remove the Log4j 1.x jar and replace it with log4j-1.2-api-2.6.2.jar, or just remove it entirely and find out what is trying to use Log4j 1.x.